# Rear Derailleur - getting stuck in largest rear cog

Tags: gears, derailleur-rear

Bike is only about 4 months old. I was indexing my gears last night, and the rear mech cage is getting stuck when shifting from largest cog to second largest cog. If I shift to the third largest cog, it will pull it down. Shifting from second largest to largest works fine.

I've played around with the cable tension, etc.

I tried pushing it inwards without the cable attached and the same still happens but it eventually pulled its self back in.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess that the cassette might be too large a range for the derailleur to cope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the b-tension (angle adjustment) screw is out too far it can cause the derailer to jam against the largest cog and get hung up a bit when shifting to smaller ones. Having too large of a largest cog will do the same thing, but that's probably not what's happening on a new bike. Other than those, something like this could result from any of the usual culprits of too much cable tension, cable friction, hanger misalignment, or damage to the derailer itself.

Answer (score 2):

On my bike I need to be on one of the smaller front cogs for lower gears to work correctly. If I'm on the large sprocket lower gears are unreliable due to the bend in the chain. My owners manuel said not to use extreme combos eg large front to large rear

Comment: True.  While many bikes (especially higher end ones) can operate smoothly "cross-chained", in general one should avoid that (and experienced cyclists do tend to avoid it, just out of habit).  It's especially true that shifting to/from the largest rear cogs will tend to be less reliable when the front is on the large cog.  And some bikes (especially older ones), with a short chain and/or insufficient tooth range in the rear derailer, will lock up in the large/large configuration.